# Display correct relationship in sql server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm create 2 tables in `sql server diagram`.
There is relations between `[Job, Job_Id]` and `[Car, Car_Id]` and `[Add, Add_Id]`
now, the diagram show them like this:

[image]

but i want to show relations like this:

[image]

Is there any special setting to show above picture?

**EDIT 1:**

**Actually I want to know if this relationship is related to which field**

**I want the relationship to be stuck in a field and not separated**

Comment: i'm a little bit confused :| what do you mean.It can be achived just moving table on diagram page on SSMS that's all.Nothing else.I'm not sure to understand which is your final goal!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,

There is no setting to do this.

You can move the positions in the join lines touch the table as it looks like you have done to create the images you have posted.  However, if you save the database diagram it will remember the positions of the table and lines to, in effect, you do achieve the view you are trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

Just mouse hover over the relation line and probably it will show you the relation (not sure though). Again, you can rearrange those lines by clicking on them and dragging them to appropriate position.

Also, for better readability you can add `Text Annotation` say `FK_Between_Job_Job-Id` by

`right click anywhere in the diagram -> choose "New Text Annotation".` 
A text box will appear, you can write text and format the text.